# Why std::make_shared has to be provided type info but std::make_pair doesn't have to?

Tags: c++

For example, when we want to create a std::pair, we can simply call:

```
std::make_pair(5, "foo");
```

But when we intend to create a shared_ptr, we have to provide type info:

```
std::make_shared<Foo>("Boo", 1024);
```

Is there any reason that makes them different?

Comment: How exactly do you expect the compiler to deduce the type you want `make_shared` to create?

Comment: std::make_shared is a variadic template passing the arguments to the constructor of the type mentioned in the template parameter

Comment: `std::make_pair` is always making a `std::pair` so it only needs to deduce the template-argument types from the function arguments. But `std::make_shared` could be making *any* type *in addition* to having to deduce the template parameter types from the function parameters. You have to specify the created type with `std::make_shared` because it doesn't have the advantage of knowing what it is going to be in advance the same way `std::make_ptr` does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function `std::make_pair<T1, T2>` creates a pair `std::pair<T1, T2>` where the types `T1` and `T2` are the types of arguments of the function. As such they can be deduced by the compiler and normally you do not need to provide them explicitly.

The function `std::make_shared<T>` creates a new object of type `T` and returns `shared_ptr<T>` storing this object. The function passes all its arguments to the constructor of `T`. There is no way for the compiler to deduce the type `T` from the arguments. Even if the argument is e.g. `const T&` the compiler cannot know if you want to create `shared_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<SomeOtherTypeWithConstructorAcceptingT>`.

Comment: Loosely related, if one wants convenience, at least `auto sp( std::make_shared<T1>() )` saves having to explicate `std::shared_ptr<T1>` to make sp, especially when the type is more complicated that just T1.

Comment: Why isn't there an overload of `make_shared` that infers `T` when you don't pass any template arguments and only pass one runtime argument?
`template <class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared(T&& arg);`

Answer (score 8):

`std::make_shared` should be called `emplace_shared` -- it calls an arbitrary ctor.

`make_pair` constructs a copy or move of its types.

They have different purposes: one is for type deduction help, the other for emplace construction.  They are both factories, hence the make name.

Comment: I always wanted to have a `make_smart` factory that not only deduces the type but also the ownership from what I want :)

Comment: @TemplateRex That requires the RPM instruction, which has poor availability on modern CPUs.

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  "`std::make_shared` should be called `emplace_shared`" ... THAT is what has been bugging me about `std::make_shared` for months.  +1  (now I can get a good nights sleep)

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_pair(T, U)` deduces that you want a `pair<T, U>`. Simple.

`std::make_shared(...)` can't really deduce anything because the arguments to the function depend on the constructor of the object you want to create, and the compiler can't guess what object you want to make.

Comment: Because that would construct a temporary `Foo`. The point of `make_shared` is that no unnecessary copying will take place - the object is instantiated and bound into a `shared_ptr` directly.

Comment: Is it any possibility to implement a self-brew `make_shared` by using `std::forward` and yet retain efficiency?

Comment: I mean a version of `make_shared` without type info.

Comment: @AhSengFan You try to avoid explicit template argument `<Foo>` and have a solution where there is an explicit constructor `Foo()` instead. Why would it be better?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Why wouldn't it? I really don't understand but I would like to listen the explanation. :)

Comment: @AhSengFan For starters, if your type does not have move constructor, any solution with explicit constructor has to create a temporary - there is no way around this. The solution with template arguments does not have such problems.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka I got it. Thx alot!!

Comment: @AhSengFan • In the `Foo` class, you could add a public `static std::shared_ptr<Foo> Make(char const* s, int n)` factory function.  Then the callsite would have to just say `auto sp = Foo::Make("Boo", 1024);`.  Moreso, if `Foo` is derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>` I recommend having a private-key constructor (since `std::make_shared` has to be able to get to the public constructor, which can be protected by using a private-key token) and public factory.

Comment: Maybe auto statement would be appropriate in the future, especially for class members: std::make_shared<auto>(...)