# Why does make_shared not use template argument deduction, when it can throw an error when it can't deduce the type of the argument?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, template-argument-deduction

Why can't `make_shared` allow for TAD, and just throw an error when it can't deduce the type? There are many types that are deducable from their values.

For instance, the compiler would know I am constructing a float here: `std::make_shared(5f)`, but I have to do `make_shared<float>(5)`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724136/why-stdmake-shared-has-to-be-provided-type-info-but-stdmake-pair-doesnt-hav) answer your question.